# NextFlow: named tuple in output block?

Tags: nextflow

I am porting logic from DSL1 to DSL2.  I have an output channel such as:

```
process foo {
  input:
    ...

  output:
    tuple val(n0), val(n1), path('/what/ever')
    ...
}
```

In the NextFlow `workflow`, I would like to to this:

```
workflow {
  ...
  foo()
  bar(foo.out.named_tuple)
}
```

where `bar` would look something like this:

```
process bar {
  input:
    tuple val(n0), val(n1), path(mypath)

  output:
    ...
}
```

and `named_tuple` would identify the output channel listed in `foo`.

Is it possible to name output tuples (or, more generally, to name tuples at all)?  If not, how do you dovetail here the output of `foo` with the `input` of `bar`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `emit` keyword for that. Check the snippet below:

```
process FOO {
  input:
  val number

  output:
  tuple val(x), val(y), val(z), emit: my_tuple
  val a
  val b

  exec:
  x = number * 2
  y = number * 3
  z = number * 4
  a = number - 1
  b = number - 2
}

workflow {
  Channel
    .of(1..4)
    | FOO
  FOO.out.my_tuple.view()
}
```

The output is:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.05.0-edge
Launching `asd.nf` [irreverent_volhard] DSL2 - revision: 573961ef9d
executor >  local (4)
[ab/3983e8] process > FOO (3) [100%] 4 of 4 ✔
[8, 12, 16]
[2, 3, 4]
[4, 6, 8]
[6, 9, 12]
```

Comment: Ok.  I was really concerned about the potentially ambiguous tuple of:  `tuple val(x), path('/p1'), path('/p2'), emit: my_tuple` ... where it is not so obvious whether `emit` is bound to the `tuple` or the nearest `path` declaration.